# How do you integrate $\int_{-a}^{a}\sin^{m}(\pi x)\,dx$ and $\int_{-a}^{a}\cos^{m}(\pi x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, computational-mathematics, trigonometric-integrals

How do you integrate
$$\int_{-a}^{a}\sin^{m}(\pi x)\,dx\quad \text{and}\quad \int_{-a}^{a}\cos^{m}(\pi x)\,dx$$

when $m$ is an odd or even natural order without using the gamma function?

Comment: Integration by parts maybe. BTW for odd $m$, the first integral is $0$.

Comment: We can reduce dimensions by using this identity:
$\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\frac{1}{n} \cos{x} \cdot \sin^{n - 1}{x} + \frac{n - 1}{n} \int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \ dx$
So that
$\int \sin^n(\pi x) \ dx = -\frac{1}{n \pi} \cos(\pi x) \cdot \sin^{n - 1}(\pi x) + \frac{n - 1}{n \pi} \int \sin^{n - 2}(\pi x) \ dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert $\sin^m(\pi x)$ or $\cos^m(\pi x)$ to a sum of constants times sines or cosines of multiple angles: complex exponentials are useful here.  Then integrate term-by-term.

For example,

$$ \eqalign{\sin^8 (\pi x) &= \left(\frac{e^{\pi i x} - e^{-\pi i x}}{2i}\right)^8 \cr
&=  \frac{1}{256} \left(e^{8 \pi i x} - 8 e^{6 \pi i x} + 28 e^{4 \pi i x} - 56
e^{2\pi i x} + 70 - 56 e^{-2\pi i x} + 28 e^{-4\pi i x} + 8 e^{-6 \pi i x} + e^{-8 \pi i x}\right)\cr
&= \frac{\cos(8 \pi x)}{128} - \frac{\cos(6 \pi x)}{16} + \frac{7 \cos(4 \pi x)}{32} - \frac{7 \cos(2 \pi x)}{16} + \frac{35}{128} \cr}$$
And integrating,
$$ \int_{-a}^a \sin^8(\pi x)\; dx = 
\frac{\sin(8\pi a)}{512\pi} - \frac{\sin(6\pi a)}{48\pi} + \frac{7 \sin(4\pi a)}{64 \pi} - \frac{7\sin(2\pi a)}{16 \pi} + \frac{35 a}{64} $$

EDIT: In the case $a=1$, $$\int_{-1}^1 \sin(n \pi x)\; dx = \int_{-1}^1 \cos(n \pi x)\; dx = 0$$ for nonzero integers $n$, so only the constant term in the expansion gives a nonzero contribution.  There is no constant term in the expansion of $\sin^{m}(\pi x)$ or $\cos^{m}(\pi x)$ if $m$ is odd, while if 
$m = 2k$ is even  the binomial theorem gives you the term: in the case of $\sin^{2k}(\pi x) = \left( \frac{e^{\pi i x} - e^{-\pi i x}}{2i}\right)^{2k}$ it's $(2i)^{-2k} (-1)^k {2k \choose k} = 2^{-2k} {2k \choose k}$, and similarly in the case of $\cos^{2k}(\pi x) =   \left( \frac{e^{\pi i x} + e^{-\pi i x}}{2}\right)^{2k}$ it's $2^{-2k} {2k \choose k}$.  Integrate that constant term from $-1$ to $1$ to get another factor of $2$.

Comment: many thanks, i need like your answer for m as the general 
solution.In particular, if a=1.

Comment: $a=1$ is special, as integrals of all but the constant term vanish... you'll get $2^{1-2k} {2k \choose k}$ for even $n = 2k$, $0$ for odd $n$.

Comment: thanks again, what about cosine if a =1 ?

Comment: Same for both cosine and sine when $a=1$.

Comment: please, can you give steps method or program code for a=1 and m is the natural order ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, time, and consideration. By your
answer , can we generalize for any $a\in R$ and $m=2k$, $a\ 2^{1-2\text{k}}\ {2k \choose k}$?
Because you are simplified the expression before integration., Is
it right?

Comment: If $a$ is not an integer, you'll have those trigonometric terms, because $\int_{-a}^a \cos(n \pi x)\; dx$ will not be $0$.

Comment: Really ,many thanks, can you explain, how constant term $\sum_{s=1}^{k}{2k \choose s}e^{2\pi xi(s-k)}\ \overset{?}{=}\ \left(-1\right)^{n}{2k \choose k}$
,in particular $\left(f+f^{-1}\right)^{2k}\overset{?}{=}\left(-1\right)^{n}{2k \choose k}$

Comment: The coefficient of $f^0$ in $(f + f^{-1})^{2k}$ is the coefficient of $f^{2k}$ in $(f^2 + 1)^{2k}$, namely the binomial coefficient ${2k \choose k}$.

Comment: many thanks Dr., you wonderful .

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_m$ be the integral $\int_{-a}^{a} \sin ^m \pi x\ dx$.

Using integration by parts,

$$\begin{align*}
S_m &= \int_{-a}^{a} \sin ^m \pi x\ dx\\
&= -\frac1\pi\int_{-a}^a\sin^{m-1}\pi x \ d \cos \pi x\\
&= -\frac1\pi\left[\sin^{m-1}\pi x\cos\pi x\right]_{-a}^a + \frac1\pi\int_{-a}^a\cos\pi x \ d\sin^{m-1}\pi x\\
&= -\frac1\pi\left[\sin^{m-1}\pi x\cos\pi x\right]_{-a}^a + (m-1)\int_{-a}^a\cos^2\pi x\sin^{m-2}\pi x\ dx\\
&= -\frac1\pi\left[\sin^{m-1}\pi x\cos\pi x\right]_{-a}^a + (m-1)\int_{-a}^a\left(1-\sin^2\pi x\right)\sin^{m-2}\pi x\ dx\\
&= -\frac1\pi\left[\sin^{m-1}\pi x\cos\pi x\right]_{-a}^a + (m-1)S_{m-2} -  (m-1)S_m\\
mS_m&= -\frac1\pi\left[\sin^{m-1}\pi x\cos\pi x\right]_{-a}^a + (m-1)S_{m-2}\\
S_m&= -\frac1{m\pi}\left[\sin^{m-1}\pi x\cos\pi x\right]_{-a}^a + \frac{m-1}mS_{m-2}\\
\end{align*}$$

This gives a reduction formula for the sine integral, and similarly for cosine. If $a$ is an integer, the first term can be simplified to zero.